# Some questions about N-channel MOSFETs

Tags: power, mosfet

I'm struggling to understand couple of basic points regarding MOSFETs.

Below is an output characteristics of an N-channel MOSFET:
[image: Signal diagram]

And below are definitions of \$ R_{DS(On)} \$ from two different sources:

[image: Equation on the on-resistance]

[image: Explanation of the on-resistance]

Is the power equation \$ P = I_{D}^2 * R_{DS(On)} \$ only valid for the linear region?
I can see that the resistance is almost constant in linear region so it makes sense to use \$ P = I_{D}^2 * R_{DS(On)} \$ formula to calculate the power.

1. But what if the MOSFET is in the saturation region? \$ V_{DS} \over I_{DS} \$ is not constant with increasing \$ V_{DS} \$ since Id almost saturates.

   It seems \$ R_{DS(On)} \$ is meaningless in saturation region. Which formula should be used for calculating the power in saturation region? \$ P = I_{D}^2 * R_{DS(On)} \$ or \$ P = V_{DS} * I_{DS} \$ ? If power for both regions are calculated different ways, should we each time check the saturation condition \$ V_{GS} > V_{Th} \$ and \$ V_{DS} > V_{GS} - V_{Th} \$ and depending on that decide which formula to be used?
2. Secondly how does the current flow after pinch off point since the depletion layer blocks/closes the inverison layer as in the below illustration:

[image: Physical construction of a MOSFET]

Answer (score 1):

The concept of Ron only makes sense where the MOSFET behaves like a resistor, which is in the linear region. In saturation the transistor is modelled by a current source (with a resistor in parallel to account for channel length modulation). So in saturation you wouldn't use something like Rds(ON).

1) The power is always given by 
$$P = V_{ds} \cdot I_{ds}$$
so it is sufficient to use the correct value for the current. Rds,on is not required but it could be used to determine the current for small values of \$V_{ds}\$.

2) The depletion region does not block the flow of current. It results in a field pointing from the drain to the channel. Electrons that reach the end of the channel get swept to the drain by this field.

Comment: so  P = Id^2 * Rds(ON) is never used when calculating the power?

Comment: It could be used, of course. But for a general expression, that could be used in a model for example it's better to use only the current.

Comment: my question was is it only used for linear region P = Id^2 * Rds(ON) . does this equation make no sense for saturation region?

Comment: The concept of Ron only makes sense where the MOSFET behaves like a resistor, which is in the linear region. In saturation the transistor is modelled by a current source (with a resistor in parallel to account for channel length modulation). So in saturation you wouldn't use something like Rds(ON).

Comment: Ok for saturation we can then ignore RDs(ON) because it doesnt make sense. But lets say you know that a MOSFET is operating in "linear region". Now for power you can both use P = Id^2 * Rds(ON) or P=Vds*Ids. Which one is more accurate? Which one would you use?

Comment: In the linear region Vds = Ids * Ron. P = Vds*Ids = Ids * Ron * Ids = Ids^2 * Ron. So both are valid.

Comment: If you are using a MOSFET as a switch, you will probably know how much current you need to switch, but you don't really care about Vds. So in that case, it is easier to just calculate I^2 Rds. You would do this, for example, when checking the thermals to figure out whether you need a heatsink, and if you do, what its thermal resistance must be.

Answer (score 0):

**Linear RDS equation**
Yes, the equation for RDS is derived in the linear mode of operation and is only valid for this case.  For example, when used as a switch.

**Power in Saturation Region**
Yes, you will need to first determine what mode of operation the MOSFET is under.  During saturation, power through it will be equal to VDS * IDS (which equals IDSAT for a long-channel approximation, where IDS has slope of 0 after VDSAT point).  Because IDSAT is roughly constant, power will increase linearly with VDS from that point out.  Remember this is an approximation that is not good for short-channel devices.

**Pinchoff**
The depiction of the channel cutting off can be misleading.  While the depletion region means there are no mobile carriers, there is an electric field established that, when a carrier enters the field, will be swept up and create a current.

Some [bedtime reading](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~hu/Chenming-Hu_ch6.pdf) for you if you want to know more.

Comment: It's called depletion region for a reason. There is no thin layer of charges.

Comment: Can a MOSFET be used as switch in saturation mode as well?

Comment: You're right there are no mobile carriers in a depletion region, but there are indeed carriers there once they are swept into the field (definition of a current).  I'll update my answer to be clearer.